# values with comma separated with point are not working in google line chart

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on google line chart now values are like `4,502.83` or `4,900.00` or `5,023.01` so the problem is, it is giving me the error

> Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value 4,502.83 does not match type number in column index 1

then I've searched on different forums and find out I've to use

```
var materialChartFormatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ pattern: "#,##0.00" });
materialChartFormatter.format(data, 1);
```

or

```
var materialChartFormatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ pattern: "#,###.##" });
materialChartFormatter.format(data, 1);
```

and also tried `pattern:'0.00'` and other patterns too like `pattern: '0.0E00'` and so on but nothing worked for me I've tried almost every pattern but no success and column type is `number` `data.addColumn('number', "MRR");` also change that type to `decimal` and `string` but that also didn't work and it gives the error.
And also tried this in option with

```
hAxis: {
     format: '#,###.##',
}
```

after all this none of them work for me so what am I doing wrong could anyone tell me, and if value is like this `4502.83` how to show this instead of `4,502.83`. help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I expect you need to provide actual number values, not formatted strings. Basically remove the commas (change the server side code)

Comment: cannot remove commas because it is required.

Comment: _values are coming from server side (PHP)_ So it's the PHP that you need to show.

Comment: Change the type from `number` to a `string`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver `4,502.83 or 4,900.00 or 5,023.01` these are the values.

Comment: @User8405526: No it isn't required.. in fact the complete opposite is required. The values you supply has nothing to do with how they will be displayed, you can change that display format to include commas.. probably by doing exactly what you have done with `hAxis` already

Comment: @musefan `hAxis` is also not working.. and show me the error `Uncaught Error: Type mismatch. Value 4,502.83 does not match type number in column index 1`.

Comment: That is NOT what I am saying... 1. change PHP server code to return proper numbers (no commas). 2. pass those proper numbers as your data 3. specify the display format to include the commas

Comment: @musefan if I just remove comma the value will be like this `4502.83111110`.

Comment: as simple as I've to show the value in google `linechart` with comma and point so how to do that???